# Formatting a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, linked-list, string-formatting, linkedhashmap

I am trying to reformat the output of a LinkedHashMap to exclude the commas and curly braces.

Here is what I have for my puts:

```
token.put("[Server.Protocol]", url.getProtocol() + "\n");
token.put("[Server.hostName]", url.getHost() + "\n");
token.put("[Server.Port]", url.getPort() + "\n");
values.add(token.toString());
```

token is my LinkedHashMap and values is my LinkedList.

Here is my output:

```
{[Server.Protocol]=https
, [Server.Name]=myserver
, [Server.Port.HTTPS]=123
}
```

Here is what I want:

```
[Server.Protocol]=https
[Server.hostName]=myserver
[Server.Port]=123
```

Here is my print method:

```
private void webconfigToINI() throws IOException {
    File fout = new File(propFile);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout, true /* append */);

        writer = new PrintWriter(fos);
        if (fos.getChannel().size() == 0)
            writer.print("[Code]\n");
        for (String value : values) {
            //writer.print(value.substring(1, value.length()-1));
            writer.print(value);
        }
        // writer.print("[Code]\n");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `token` is a misleading name. It implies **singular**, but obviously you put multiple values into it. So `tokens` would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `toString` on your map you can use this:

```
String string = token.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue())
                      .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

If you can't use Java 8 then you have to iterate and joining your data retrieving them from the map using `entrySet()`, as the following code:

```
String string = "";
for (Map.Entry<String, String> value: token.entrySet()) {
    string = string + value.getKey() + "="+value.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
values.add(token.toString());
```

You are calling the `toString()` on your map object. Which will invoke the `toString()` implemented in the [AbstractMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html) base class. That method iterates the entries, and adds the { } braces around its entries.

Thus, simple answer: do not call that method!

Instead, you could iterate the [entrySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#entrySet()) of your map object manually, pull keys, values, and write those into your file.

Beyond that: do you need that map in the first place? If `token` is only used to call `toString()`, to fetch those strings ... then it would be more efficient to use a StringBuilder instead. Simply push your **strings** into that builder, and use that in the end.

Answer (score 0):

My one-liner (with enough code before and after to make a complete example):

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> token = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    token.put("[Server.Protocol]", "https");
    token.put("[Server.hostName]", "myserver");
    token.put("[Server.Port]", "123");
    String value = token.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    System.out.println(value);
```

Output:

> ```
> [Server.Protocol]=https
> [Server.hostName]=myserver
> [Server.Port]=123
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you are using java 8 or later you can try this :

```
 LinkedHashMap<String, String> token = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        token.put("[Server.Protocol]", "https" + "\n");
        token.put("[Server.hostName]", "myserver" + "\n");
        token.put("[Server.Port]", "8080" + "\n");


        String val = token.entrySet().stream().map(k -> k.getKey()+ "="+ 
    k.getValue()).collect(joining(""));
        System.out.println(val);
```

the value printed will look like what you are expecting
cheers

Comment: do not forget to add import for collectors    import java.util.stream.Collectors